# Perl: pipe a serialized hash to a forked process

Tags: perl, serialization, fork, storable

I don't know whats wrong with my code. I'm trying to serialize a hash inside the parent and pipe it to the fork, where it should be deserialized.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable qw(freeze thaw);
use IO::Pipe;

my $pipe_to_fork = IO::Pipe->new();

my $fork = fork;
if ($fork == 0) { # actual fork scope
  $pipe_to_fork->reader();
  my $hash_serialized = <$pipe_to_fork>; # wait and retrieve the serialized hash from parent
  chomp $hash_serialized;
  my %hash_rebuild = %{thaw($hash_serialized)}; # deserialize the retrieved serialized hash
  exit;
}

my %hash = ('key1' => "val1", 'key2' => "val2");

$pipe_to_fork->writer();
$pipe_to_fork->autoflush(1);

my $hash_serialized = freeze(\%hash); # serialize the hash
print $pipe_to_fork $hash_serialized."\n";
sleep 5;

exit;
```

... produces the following error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at ./fork_serialize.pl line 14, <GEN0> line 1.
```

Is there something wrong with the pipe? It seems that `thaw` doesn't deserialize the retrieved scalar value. Maybe the retrieved scalar value isn't correct.

I've tried to do some semilar things without forking or piping, and its working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable qw(freeze thaw);

my %hash = ('key1' => "value1", 'key2' => "value2");
my $hash_serialized = freeze(\%hash);
my %hash_rebuild = %{thaw($hash_serialized)};

print $hash_rebuild{'key2'}."\n";
```

Not much of a logical difference, he? It would be nice if anyone can explain me more of this behavior.

Comment: Check that the number of bytes sent and received is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble is that you're trying to use a line-based protocol (appending the `"\n"` on the write side, using `<>` and `chomp` on the read side) but your data is not text and can contain its own `"\n"`s so your reader stops at the first one and chops it off.

You need to use some other method of signaling the end of the serialized data, for example you could close the pipe on the write end and keep going until EOF on the read end. In fact, `Storable` has a pair of functions designed for this exact situation: `store_fd` and `fd_retrieve`. They'll do the transfer in a way that detects the end without an EOF, so you can keep the pipe open for more transfers.

Here's a version of the guts of your program using the `fd` functions from `Storable`:

```
if ($fork == 0) { # actual fork scope
  $pipe_to_fork->reader();
  my %hash_rebuild = %{fd_retrieve($pipe_to_fork)}; # deserialize the retrieved serialized hash
  use Data::Dumper;$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;print Dumper \%hash_rebuild;
  exit;
}

my %hash = ('key1' => "val1", 'key2' => "val2");

$pipe_to_fork->writer();
$pipe_to_fork->autoflush(1);

store_fd(\%hash, $pipe_to_fork);
```

Comment: Thanks! This really explains a lot and it's working now. I've already had a slight clue that some characters in the string may interfere with the use of such per line reading.

Comment: I didn't mean to leave my debugging `Data::Dumper` in there... but it's not doing any harm so I won't remove it now.

Comment: I didn't take the Data::Dumper line into my code ;) - but if i need further debugging i will use it maybe.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're assuming the hash is `freezed` into one single line. But that's not always the case, since `$hash_serialized` could be a string containing multiple `\n`s.

So instead of reading only one line in child side, you should read until the EOF and concatenate all the lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable qw(freeze thaw);
use IO::Pipe;

my $pipe_to_fork = IO::Pipe->new();

my $fork = fork;
if ($fork == 0) { # actual fork scope
  $pipe_to_fork->reader();
  my $hash_serialized;
  $hash_serialized .= $_ while (<$pipe_to_fork>);
  my %hash_rebuild = %{thaw($hash_serialized)}; # deserialize the retrieved serialized hash
  print $hash_rebuild{key1};
  exit;
}

my %hash = ('key1' => "val1", 'key2' => "val2");

$pipe_to_fork->writer();
$pipe_to_fork->autoflush(1);

my $hash_serialized = freeze(\%hash); # serialize the hash
print $pipe_to_fork $hash_serialized;

exit;
```

> **Output:** val1

Comment: Also thanks, but the solution of Wumpus Q. Wumbley is a bit nicer i think. Nonetheless its a noteworthy alternative and explains the whole thing a bit further.